# React Project - Node sass could not find a binding for your current environment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules, node-sass

I am using React

> "react": "^16.13.1",

and I want to use Sass so, I install Node-sass:

> "node-sass": "^4.13.1",

And I have this error:

[image]

I tried to solve as follow:

> npm rebuild node-sass
>   I deleted node-modules folder and ran npm i again

but the error persists

I updated node version to:

> v13.13.0

And again

[image]

This app has a dockerfile with:

> FROM node:13-alpine

Comment: At first clear cache npm clean cahce . If not solved then uninstall node js and reinstall latest version . Also try with another machine

Answer (score 1):

You can't install on your Mac and then share the node_modules folder with an Alpine (or any other) Docker container. Install inside of the container if you're using any native modules like node-sass.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn´t work. 

Inside of the container I ran npm install and  npm install node-sass. Also I create .dockerignorefile with node_modules folder but I ran npm i in my host and this folder was copied in the container